# Code error numeric issue

Tags: php

I have an avatar upload plugin for my website and am seeing this code error on the front end page...

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /xxx/xxx/xxx/media.php on
>   line 647

**the code on the line 647 throwing the error is:**

```
$matched = ( abs( $constrained_size[0] - $expected_size[0] ) <= 1 && abs( $constrained_size[1] - $expected_size[1] ) <= 1 );
```

**the full code above and below is:**

```
// If the image dimensions are within 1px of the expected size, we consider it a match.
$matched = ( abs( $constrained_size[0] - $expected_size[0] ) <= 1 && abs( $constrained_size[1] - $expected_size[1] ) <= 1 );
```

any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: tldr.. *A non-numeric value encountered* - check your vars for non-numeric values..

Comment: Insufficient question details.  Cannot reproduce.  Off-topic: Why isn't my code working.

Comment: Please remove javascript tag

Comment: Don't declare single-use variables.

Comment: @mickmackusa how do I do that sorry I am a newbie, appreciate the help

Comment: Print out your variables for us.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/cFSbB  look at what happens when one of your values is not a number. Is one of the values `NaN` because of an earlier calculation?  Do you have a missing image file in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

This code solved it for me.

```
// If the image dimensions are within 1px of the expected size, we consider it a match.
    $matched = ( abs( (int)$constrained_size[0] - (int)$expected_size[0] ) <= 1 && abs( (int)$constrained_size[1] - (int)$expected_size[1] ) <= 1 );
```

Answer (score -1):

try to check your variables i think you use string as integer. you can insert a log or file_put_content to check all your variables data ($constrained_size and $expected_size)
if you make sure of your variables are Integer then try to cast them to Integer maybe php count them as string anyway
use ---> (int)$constrained_size and (int)$expected_size

Comment: If you went to the doctor because you thought you had a flesh-eating ulcer on your arm, and your doctor said, "Here, put this long-sleeve shirt on -- you'll never see it."  You'd never go back to that doctor again ...assuming you survived.  Whacking `(int)` on the flawed value(s) will likely damage the data and provide inaccurate results.  Please remove this post because it offers ill-considered advice and degrades the expected level of quality on StackOverflow.  Furthermore, please do not answer unclear/incomplete answers on StackOverflow.